# Android: Set HttpUrlConnection speed limit

Tags: android, performance, http, limit

is it possible to set a download speed limit for a HttpUrlConnection in Android?

My app displays data. The data is retrieved from a web server. 
There are two types of data that are loaded from the web server to display them in my app:
- small files (about 1 MB)
- big files (about 100 MB)

The problem is:
When I start to downlaod a big file, which is about 100 MB and may take about 5 minutes,
my app is nearly unuseable in the meantime.

A typical scenario is:
User klicks on a big file --> big file is downloaded in the background.
In the meantime the User wants to display another little file (1 MB, should take about a few seconds to load it from server ). But the problem is, that the first downlaod (loading the big file) uses the whole bandwith and therefore the download of the small file takes about 2 minutes (instead of a few seconds).

So I would like to set a speet limit for big files (for example half of the bandwith etc.) or to implement some priority queue for downloads...

How do I set the download limit?

Comment: If you are using SDK => 9 then you should use the [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) API

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is either use the DownloadManager as the previous commenter suggested, if you're developing for API level 9+. The trouble is with this is that downloads are shown in the notification bar and you might not want that.

As far as I can see there is no way to limit bandwidth on a specific download using the HttpClient used with Android. But I am guessing that you are downloading the file using an AsyncTask per file, and AsyncTasks are executed serially therefore that might explain why the 2nd file doesn't start downloading.

I strongly suggest looking at [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/blob/master/README.md) which is perfect for this type of background downloading. I'm pretty sure you will be able to download multiple files at once as well.